# Search the file for the extension specified by the keyboard. Shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I tried to specify file extension by the keyboard and then find all these files in current directory, but I can't read the extension from variable.

```
echo Input file type:
read EXT
find . -name '*.{EXT}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Input file type:"
read EXT
find .  -type f -name "*.$EXT"
```

This script will search files in current directory and its sub directories. You can use `maxdepth` if you want to optimize this

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -type f -name "*.$EXT"
```

`-maxdepth X`:  Search current directory as well as all sub-directories X levels deep.